# Will MessageBox() "eat" my user-defined message?

Tags: c, winapi

I have a UI thread and another thread, I want to send a user-defined message using `PostMessage()` from the other trhead to the UI thread.

If the UI thread displays a message box, and then I send the user-defined message, will the message loop of the message box retrieve the user-defined message from the UI thread message queue, and hence the user-defined message will be lost?!

Comment: IME, no, this does not happen.  The 'USER+' messages are dispatched to the HWND you specified.  Even if this a GUI Window 'underneath' the modal messageBox, it will still receive and process the USER message.

Comment: @MartinJames comment should be right, but an easy way to answer this question for sure is to test it! Override your UI thread loop in the main app and print out a log if your user defined message arrives. Please share your findings, this is interesting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PostMessage()` is not a problem. `MessageBox()` runs its own message loop to make the message box modal, but makes a call to `DispatchMessage()` and that function makes sure that the correct window procedure gets called for any message that was posted/sent to any window.

You could only make this mistake if you were calling `PostThreadMessage()` instead.  That is never safe if the receiving thread displays dialogs or enters modal loops.  Raymond Chen wrote a couple of blog articles about that:

[Thread messages are eaten by modal loops](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/04/26/412116.aspx)

[Why do messages posted by PostThreadMessage disappear?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/09/30/9901065.aspx)

A possible corner-case is posting a message that requires the message loop to process the message instead of the window procedure.  Like a shortcut keystroke.